# Build a Debian package for Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deb, python-packaging

Can someone advise me how to build a Debian package for Tensorflow? So, I can install TF with Linux command like

> dpkg -i tensorflow.deb

Thanks;

Answer (score 5):

It's a wee bit complicated by the fact that some packages have `(Build-)Depends:` you need packaged first.

[This Debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=804612) is the so-called 'Intent To Package' but it itself depends on `bazel` being packaged first.  So in order to get `tf`, you need to package `bazel`.  Not a small task.

Comment: tf has some alternative build systems: Cmake and Makefile. Debian bug 804612 has message from Lumin "*CMake build is available, but it still needs an amount of tweaks to meet the requirements of  Policy*." Any idea what are issues with tf+cmake for debian policy?